# Python linear regression, first order polynomial

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I have a data set that I'm asked to fit a first degree polynomial to.

[image]

I'm using the `numpy` function `polyfit`, but I'm getting some pretty strange results
I use the following code to find that polynomial and plot it

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('men-olympics-100.txt')
year = data[:,0]
time = data[:,1]
plt.scatter(year, time)
xplot=np.linspace(1896,2008,100)
poly =np.polyfit(year,time,1)
print(poly)
yplot = poly[0]+poly[1]*(xplot)
plt.plot(xplot,yplot)
```

This is the resulting plot

[image]

Clearly I have done something wrong here, but I cannot figure out exactly where. Am I using `polyfit` wrong, or am I plotting it wrong?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html "Returns: Polynomial coefficients, highest power first"

Comment: Thus you're plotting it wrongly. Also, it's highly advisable to provide some starting parameters to help the convergence. this might not be the case, but in many cases most of the problems are solved by that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
yplot = poly[0]+poly[1]*(xplot)
```

needs to be like this

```
yplot = poly[1]+poly[0]*(xplot)
```

---

Or more generally (Thanks @Victor Chubukov)

```
np.polyval(poly,xplot)
```

Comment: or more generally, `np.polyval(poly,xplot)`